# How to group the same values into same key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, iterable-unpacking

I have an assignment to do this things without import any helpful function, could you guys help me?
Thanks!

```
data = [
    ['num','e1','e2','e3'],
    ['2002','p','r','i'],
    ['2002','k','r','i'],
    ['2001','k','r','e'],
    ['2004','p','a','p'],
    ['2004','p','s','f']
]

newlist = [
    {'num': '2001', 'e1': 'k', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'e'},
    {'num': '2002', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'i'},
    {'num': '2002', 'e1': 'k', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'i'},
    {'num': '2004', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 'a', 'e3': 'p'},
    {'num': '2004', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 's', 'e3': 'f'}
]
```

How can I convert `newlist` into this by `num` is main key and next key is `e1`

```
{
    '2001':{
        'k':[{'num': '2001', 'e1': 'k', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'e'}]
    },
    '2002':{
        'k':[{'num': '2002', 'e1': 'k', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'i'}],
        'p':[{'num': '2002', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'i'}]
    },
    '2004':{
        'p':[{'num': '2004', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 'a', 'e3': 'p'}, {'num': '2004', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 's', 'e3': 'f'}]
    }
}
```

2001 and 2002 have only k and k have only one data so it will be the only one member of k
you will see its form `{ num:  {e1: [ {'num':..., 'e1': ..., 'e2': ... }, ... ], ...}, ... }`

Comment: There are many [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69587757/21146235) on this topic, perhaps they would be helpful to look at

Comment: You didn't provide the code you've tried and from my POV the description is completely not understandable to be honest.

Comment: @Gameplay Note that code being added is only a requirement for debugging questions. This being a 'how to' question, code is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to loop through the input list (`data` or `newlist`) and use [`.setdefault`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/setdefault) and `.append` to fill up the nested dictionary or lists.

---

To get the nested dictionary from `data`:

```py
result, kList, vData = {}, data[0], data[1:]
for r in vData:
    k_outer, k_inner = r[:2]
    dict_inner = result.setdefault(k_outer, {})
    list_inner = dict_inner.setdefault(k_inner, [])
    list_inner.append(dict(zip(kList, r)))
```

---

To get the nested dictionary from `newlist`:

```py
# newlist = [dict(zip(data[0],r)) for r in data[1:]] # <-- get newlist from data

result, k_outer_key, k_inner_key = {}, 'num', 'e1'
for r in newlist:
    k_outer, k_inner = r.get(k_outer_key), r.get(k_inner_key)
    dict_inner = result.setdefault(k_outer, {})
    list_inner = dict_inner.setdefault(k_inner, [])
    list_inner.append(r)
```

---

You can also use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) to create a nested dictionary containing empty lists and then loop through `data` or `newlist` and add each dictionary in the input list to whichever list it belongs to in the nested dictionary.

(You could filter the input list for each nested key right away with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) when you're defining the nested dictionary, but doing it in a separate loop actually reduces the total number of times you loop through the input data.)

---

To get the nested dictionary from `data`, you can use

```py
kList, vData = data[0], data[1:]

result = {k_outer: {
    k_inner: [] for k, k_inner, *_ in vData if k==k_outer
} for k_outer in {k1 for k1, *_ in vData}}

for r in vData: result[r[0]][r[1]].append(dict(zip(kList,r)))

## OR 
''' ## [SLIGHTLY LESS EFFICIENT]
kList, vData = data[0], data[1:]
result = {k_outer: {
    k_inner: [dict(zip(kList,x)) for x in vData if x[0]==k_outer and x[1]==k_inner] 
    for k, k_inner, *_ in vData if k==k_outer
} for k_outer in {k1 for k1, *_ in vData}}
'''
```

---

To get the nested dictionary from `newlist`, you can use

```py
k_outer, k_inner = 'num', 'e1'

result = {k: {
    d.get(k_inner): [] for d in newlist if k==d.get(k_outer)
} for k in {r.get(k_outer) for r in newlist}}

for r in newlist: result[r.get(k_outer)][r.get(k_inner)].append(r)

## OR 
''' ## [SLIGHTLY LESS EFFICIENT]
k_outer, k_inner = 'num', 'e1'
result = {k: {d.get(k_inner): [
    x for x in newlist if x.get(k_outer)==k and x.get(k_inner)==d.get(k_inner)
] for d in newlist if k==d.get(k_outer)} for k in {r.get(k_outer) for r in newlist}}
'''
```

---

Whichever approach is taken, `result` should look like

> ```py
> {
>   '2004': {
>     'p': [{'num': '2004', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 'a', 'e3': 'p'}, {'num': '2004', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 's', 'e3': 'f'}]
>   },
>   '2002': {
>     'p': [{'num': '2002', 'e1': 'p', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'i'}],
>     'k': [{'num': '2002', 'e1': 'k', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'i'}]
>   },
>   '2001': {
>     'k': [{'num': '2001', 'e1': 'k', 'e2': 'r', 'e3': 'e'}]
>   }
> }
> ```